# How to disable autorotation for iPhone application?

Tags: ios6, autorotate

I am implementing an Universal application. In my application I need to Autorotate the screen for the iPad only not for the iPhone. How can I do that? I tried with the following code but it is not working.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it by making changes to the properties in plist file.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling to set in UIViewController's  `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientation` methods, with no success in iOS6, I found the most effective is to set it in app delegate.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

However returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown` was crashing my app. I don't know what I was doing wrong!